# Jquery Ajax Send to plugin action WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using ajax to send form data to a plugin action and I can't get the jQuery to link to the function. The jQuery seems to be sending the code perfectly as i can see via the headers. However the WordPress php function call isn't being actioned. Can't figure it out.

```
$.ajax({
        url: cjdAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        action: 'cjd_send_test_email',
        data: {
            'email': email, 
            'subject': subject,
            'content': content
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
            $(".test-box .spinner").hide();
            $(".test-email-message").slideDown();
        }

    });
```

PHP code

```
wp_localize_script( 'cjd_admin_script', 'cjdAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cjd_send_test_email', 'cjd_send_email_test' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cjd_send_test_email', 'cjd_send_email_test' );

function cjd_send_email_test(){
  echo $_POST['content'];
  echo $_POST['subject'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` param should be part of the `data` array:

```
data: {
    action: 'cjd_send_test_email',
    email: email, 
    subject: subject,
    content: content
},
```

Comment: Knew it would be something simple ;) - Thanks for the help.